# Move the most revent commits to a different branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-branch-sculpting

This is the Situation in my git repository:
I have two branches "dev" and "fix" and need to move the three most recent commits on the fix branch to the dev branch. The head is on the last commit on the dev branch (E). 
So i need to go from this:

```
dev   A
       \
fix     B - C - D - E
                    ^HEAD
```

to this:

```
dev    A - C - D - E
        \          ^HEAD
fix      B
```

I'd appreciate any help on how to accomplish this with git commands (it's an offline repository)

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick. Git Cherry-pick command will come to your use.

Answer (score 2):

it's simple

```
git checkout dev
git cherry-pick fix~3..fix # apply the last 3 revisions from fix
git checkout fix
git reset --hard HEAD~3 # set fix 3 revisions behind
```

You are rewriting history, in case it's not obvious, it's more like:

```
dev    A - C' - D' - E'
        \            ^HEAD
fix      B
```